# Node absolute value is not working with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I'm using web pack in my server file, but when I tried to use __dirname without web pack it works normally like '/Users/user_name/Desktop/project_name', but when running the built file by webpack while doing a log on the __dirname it returns simple '/'. Why does this happen?

Directory is like:

```
/node_modules
/src
--/cloud
----/main.js
--/static
----/markups
------/index.html
----/scripts
------/index.js
----/bundles
/package.json
/webpack.config.js
```

The config file as

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function (x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function (mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'server',
    target: 'node',
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'cloud'),
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname),
      filename: 'server.js'
    },
    externals: nodeModules,
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015']}
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      root: path.join(__dirname),
      fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'client',
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'static'),
    entry: {
      index: './scripts/index.js'
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'static', 'bundles'),
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0']
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      root: path.join(__dirname),
      fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack uses it's own module to handle the `__dirname`, and the default config is `mock` which means `“/“`. That's why you do not get an absolute path.

[Ref: api in modules # __dirname](https://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html#__dirname)

*(I can only answer you for `Why does this happen?`
I get the same issue like you do but still finding the solution, can someone could give some hint? ;) )*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node

 
to set your node `__dirname`